Algebraic numbers with lacunary vanishing polynomial
For $n\geq 2,$ let $X_n$ be the set of all algebraic numbers $x$ that have an annihilating polynomial $P\in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $P$ has at most $n$ non-zero coefficients. Note that I'm only asking $P$ to be an annihilating polynomial, and not necessarily the minimal polynomial of $x.$
For example, $X_2$ consists of all $k$-th roots of rational numbers (where $k\geq 1$). Any element in $X_2$ that is not rational or a root of unity has vanishing trace, therefore $X_2\neq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}.$
One obviously has $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\underset{n\geq 2}{\bigcup} X_n.$ Is the sequence $(X_n)_{n\geq 2}$ a strictly increasing sequence ? I don't even know how to prove that $X_3\neq \overline{\mathbb{Q}}.$

$X_n\ne\overline{\mathbb Q}$. If $P$ has at most $m+1$ nonzero coefficients, by Descartes' rule of signs, it has at most $2m$ real roots. If $P(\alpha)=0$ for $\alpha\in\overline{\mathbb Q}$, $P\in\mathbb Q[x]$, then $P$ is divisible by a minimal polynomial $f$ of $\alpha$. Take $\alpha=\sum_1^n\sqrt{p_i}$, where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime, along with its $2^n$ (real) conjugates to get many real roots

I'd encourage posting these comments in an answer.

@user491858 If you hesitate to provide your solution as an answer because an essential idea was provided in a previous comment by someone else, you can make your answer "community wiki".

As suggested, I am combining the comments to provide an answer.
We have that $X_n \ne \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ for any $n \geq 1$.
By Decartes' rule of signs, if you have an irreducible polynomial with exactly $n$ non-zero terms but $2n−2$ real roots then it is an element of $_n$ but not of $_{n−1}$. But you can easily write down such a polynomial explicitly, for example:
$$\displaystyle P()=3\prod_{k=1}^{n−1}(x^2−4k^2)+2.$$
This is irreducible by Eisenstein's Criterion, it has degree $2n−2$
and moreover has $2n−2$ real roots. To see this, note that the sign of the value of $P(x)$ alternates for $x=1,3,5,…,2n−1$ giving $n−1$ positive roots, and then $P(−x)=P(x)$.
